# Direction needed: finding terms in a corpus

Tags: python, nlp, lemmatization

My question isn't about a specific code issue, but rather about the best direction to take on a Natural Language Processing challenge.

I have a collection of several hundreds of Word and PDF files (from which I can then export the raw text) on the one hand, and a list of terms on the other. Terms can consist in one or more words. What I need to do is identify in which file(s) each term is used, applying stemming and lemmatization.

How would I best approach this? I know how to extract text, apply tokenization, lemmatization, etc., but I'm not sure how I could search for occurrences of terms in lemmatized form inside a corpus of documents.

Any hint would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create an inverted index of the documents, where you record the locations of each word in a list, with the word form as the index.

Then you create a secondary index, where you have as key the lemmatised forms, and as values a list of forms that belong to the lemma.

When you do a lookup of a lemmatised word, eg *go*, you go to the secondary index to retrieve the inflected forms, *go*, *goes*, *going*, *went*; next you go to the inverted index and get all the locations for each of the inflected forms.

For ways of implementing this in an efficient manner, look at Witten/Moffat/Bell, *Managing Gigabytes*, which is a fantastic book on this topic.

UPDATE: for multi-word units, you can work those out in the index. Looking for "software developer", look up "software" and "developer", and then merge the locations: everytime their location differs by 1, they are adjacent and you have found it. Discard all the ones where they are further apart.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. But then how would you work with terms consisting in multiple words? Let's say one of the terms is "software developer" and the corps might contain occurrences of "software", "developer" and "software developer". I'm guessing I'll need to add both the words and a very long list of, say, tri-grams.

Comment: @mrgou I have updated my answer. This approach takes some initial time to create indices etc, but finding stuff is then very fast.